# repo: command not found?

Tags: android, git, repo

I am new to git and repo. I am in window 7 so I use cygwin. I have installed git from cygwin setup. After that I try to repo with the following command in cygwin.

```sh
$ repo init-u git://android.git.kernel.org/platform/manifest.git
```

I get an error like these:

```sh
bash: repo: command not found
```

I think I need to setup cygwin for repo. What do I need next to get repo?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install Android's repo on my Ubuntu system?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4350344/how-to-install-androids-repo-on-my-ubuntu-system)

Answer (score 15):

**Case 1: Not installed google repo yet?**

```
mkdir ~/bin
PATH=~/bin:$PATH
curl https://storage.googleapis.com/git-repo-downloads/repo > ~/bin/repo
chmod a+x ~/bin/repo
```

Use the following checksums when required:

For version 1.25 it is
`d06f33115aea44e583c8669375b35aad397176a411de3461897444d247b6c220`

For version 1.26, it is `0cf5f52bcafb8e1d3ba0271b087312f6117b824af272bedd4ee969d52363a86b`

**Case 2: Already have google repo Installed, still wondering what went wrong ?**

Add 
`PATH=~/bin:$PATH` to the end of file ~/.bashrc
and then run 
`source ~/.bashrc`

Comment: oh yeah, You are my life-safer!! It works! yeah thanks

Answer (score 8):

You still need to install repo. repo is a third party tool built on top of git. See:
http://source.android.com/source/downloading.html
for how to install

Comment: The link above says nothing about how to install. See this link instead: http://source.android.com/source/downloading.html

Comment: My problem was that repo was not executable, needed this `chmod +x repo`

Answer (score 7):

I have the same problem and I have to do:
`$ PATH=~/bin:$PATH` every time I repo sync but at least it works.

Comment: saved my day with this least voted answer!
Why is this not upvoted yet

Comment: I followed case1, case2 from ishandutta2007 reply. Wasn't quite enough. After doing this, it worked!

Answer (score 6):

add line
export `PATH=~/bin:$PATH` in file `~/.bashrc`

Answer (score 3):

edit .bash_profile and uncomment these fields.  (any text editor will do)

```
# Set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
# if [ -d "${HOME}/bin" ] ; then
#   PATH="${HOME}/bin:${PATH}"
# fi
```

Restart CYGWIN.

Answer (score 0):

Check and see if you have both .profile & .bash_profile in the working directory.

If you do, it's possible that the export command in both is actually conflicting in your shell. Making the output look something like this in Windows...

```
PATH="C:/Windows/path/to/repo/Windows/path/to/repo:$PATH"
export PATH
```

That's what happened to my bash shell anyway. It is correct that the 2 files interact with Bash or Cygwin differently, however if you have redundant inputs, they will compile together...

Answer (score 0):

**This answer for android build system error**
For Python 3

If you get a "/usr/bin/env 'python' no such file or directory" error message, use one of the following solutions:
If your Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS is a newly installed (vs. upgraded) Linux version:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python
```

f using Git version 2.19 or greater, you can specify --partial-clone when performing repo init. This makes use of Git's partial clone capability to only download Git objects when needed, instead of downloading everything. Because using partial clones means that many operations must communicate with the server, use the following if you're a developer and you're using a network with low latency:

```
repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest -b master --partial-clone --clone-filter=blob:limit=10M
```

you can see document in
[Downloading the Source](https://source.android.com/setup/build/downloading)