# How to install Android's repo on my Ubuntu system?

Tags: android, ubuntu, repo

I want to install `repo` for working with the Android source files. How to install `repo`?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

From https://source.android.com/source/downloading#installing-repo:

```
$ curl https://storage.googleapis.com/git-repo-downloads/repo > ~/bin/repo
$ chmod a+x ~/bin/repo
$ mkdir working-directory-name 
$ cd working-directory-name 
$ repo init -u git://android.git.kernel.org/platform/manifest.git
```

Authoritative instructions

Comment: Good answer when it was posted.  The link and steps have changed since.

https://source.android.com/docs/setup/download#installing-repo

Answer (score 12):

If you are using Ubuntu 16.04, just use this command line:

`sudo apt-get install repo -y`

Comment: Also available on Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: It should be `apt-get`.

Comment: I used this APT repository version for a while, but since it is a bit old, it gives a warning saying there is a new version available. My users complained so I now install latest version using the other methods.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, we may manually add apt source to install a newer version, from my experience for updating some software like GCC

Answer (score 7):

Many distros include repo, so you might be able to install from there.

```sh
# Debian/Ubuntu.
$ sudo apt-get install repo

# Gentoo.
$ sudo emerge dev-vcs/repo

## Linux Mint
$ sudo rm /etc/apt/preferences.d/nosnap.pref
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt install snapd
$ sudo snap install git-repo
```

You can install it manually as well as it's a single script.

```sh
$ mkdir -p ~/.bin
$ PATH="${HOME}/.bin:${PATH}"
$ curl https://storage.googleapis.com/git-repo-downloads/repo > ~/.bin/repo
$ chmod a+rx ~/.bin/repo
```

See Official website: https://gerrit.googlesource.com/git-repo/

Answer (score 3):

The location changed to http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/git-repo-downloads/repo:

```sh
curl http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/git-repo-downloads/repo > ~/bin/repo
```

Comment: Hello David,
Could not initialize repo client using the below command.

$ repo init -u git://android.git.kernel.org/platform/manifest.git and Tried to do it with 

repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest

but not working. Where is the latest URL to initialize repo?

Answer (score 2):

Repo is included in `phablet-tools` package which is available from official package repository for Ubuntu releases starting from 14.04