# How to install Google repo?

Tags: android, macos, repo

I am trying to install google repo on my machine. The reference link is `http://source.android.com/source/downloading.html#installing-repo`

After  `chmod a+x ~/bin/repo`, and after installing repo go ahead with further steps.

Do I have execute the repo file? I just understood that I need to install repo before proceeding to further steps but how? I am new to mac and have no idea how to execute a file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install Android's repo on my Ubuntu system?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4350344/how-to-install-androids-repo-on-my-ubuntu-system)

Answer (score 4):

You can type in terminal the following comands:

```
   curl https://storage.googleapis.com/git-repo-downloads/repo > ~/bin/repo
   chmod a+x ~/bin/repo
```

Comment: bash: /home/ubuntu/bin/repo: Is a directory

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience of using repo on mac, but according my experience on linux, after you change the mode, i.e run 'chmod' to give repo, in fact python scripts, the right of execute, you should add '~/bin/repo' to you PATH environment variables.  After doing these config, you can repo command, such as 'repo init', 'repo sync' anywhere you like.